# Javascript - move "<script src" to "<script>"

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am writing a program in Python but need to make use of a Google API which uses JavaScript which I don't know so I am writing as little of the code in JavaScript and using JS2PY to run it under Python. The problem is, JS2PY doesn't seem to support HTML tags.

I have -

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>

function initMap() {

  var swl = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: 55.857128, lng: -4.272051});
  var nel = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: 55.867147, lng: -4.245272});
  var boundsRectangle = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swl,nel);

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    bounds: boundsRectangle,
    types: ['store']
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    var finalResults = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      finalResults.push(results[i].name);
      finalResults.push(results[i].geometry.location);
    }
    window.alert(finalResults);
  }
}


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDU-I_Cth5BjAHVr15YKAa8A5-xbwmp74M&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is I can only paste what's between the `<script></script>` tags into JS2PY and have no idea how to include the

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDU-I_Cth5BjAHVr15YKAa8A5-xbwmp74M&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

line into the main code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include your JS2PY code ?

Comment: I think you are missing some understanding of backend vs frontend ... you should just be able to write normal html+js+css for the frontend ... you shouldnt need python(WRT the frontend) and if its the backend than there is no reason for HTML ...

Comment: You should probably try to find a Python API for what you are trying to achieve or run JS directly (via Node.js) instead of using JS2PY.

Comment: there is NO reason you should have to mix html/js + python ... these are different parts of the stack ...

Comment: I understand the the JS API would normally only be used for the front end but sadly Google doesn't seem to have a Python API for searching for places within a given rectangle, the python one strangely only accepts within a given radius from a point, not within a rectangle. So I need JS that will return me a list of place coordinates & names within a given rectangle back into python, that's all.

I haven't figured out JS2PY yet, for now I am just directly copy&pasting the javascript from between the script tags - no complaints, complains as soon as the html tag is included.